# Under what situations would it matter whether information is stored in the stateful widget class or the state class?

Tags: flutter, statefulwidget

Here is `property` as a part of the `StatefulWidget` class

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  String property = "";
  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Here is how I would access`property` from the `State`'s `build` method:
`widget.property`

Here is `property` as a part of the `StatefulWidget`'s `State` class

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  String property = "";
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Here is how I would access it from the `State`'s `build` method:
`property`

Looks to me like I can achieve the exact same things regardless of whether `property` is part of the `StatefulWidget` class or part of the `State` class.

Am I right or wrong, and if I am wrong, why?

Comment: I would say that's a practice, there is no point to declare a variable in the State object if it doesn't relate to any lifecycle methods of a `StatefulWidget` or doesn't even relate to the state updates!